# How to remove code duplicity in python list comprehension?

Tags: python, list-comprehension, code-duplication

How to resolve the following code duplicity by combining into one list comprehension?

```
 myList   =[ //someList      ]      
 thierList=[ //someOtherList ]      

 if name:
          [x for x in range(2,100) if x%2 and x in mylist and x not in theirList]

 else:
          [x for x in range(2,100) if x in mylist and x not in theirList]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[x for x in range(2,100) if x in mylist and x not in theirList if not name or x%2 ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you can use sets http://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html

```
set(myList + thierList)
```